# REST API (Lambda integration) deployment using Terraform - POST is giving 200, but GET is giving 500

Tags: api, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a REST API with 2 methods GET and POST. Here is the work I have done:

1. Using Terraform to deploy AWS services.
2. Created 2 REST API methods - GET and POST.
3. Integrated API Gateway to AWS lambda. I created two lambdas, one for each method. The objective is to get "Hello World" as a response. The two lambdas (handlers) are identical in code.

The problem: After the deployment, it worked as expected (200) when I tried to hit POST. However, GET is giving a 500 error. This is what I see on the AWS console.

- [When I am using type='MOCK' for GET]Execution failed due to configuration error: No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured. Endpoint Response Status Code: 200
- [When I am using type = 'AWS_PROXY' for GET] Lambda invocation failed with status: 403. Lambda request id: 5b23639d-f6fb-4130-acf0-15db9a2f76b0
- Method completed with status: 500

**Why is it that POST is working and GET is throwing an error?** Any leads to rectifying this error or providing some explanation are appreciated.

Below is my Terraform configuration.

Note: I included only the "aws_api_gateway_*" resources. IAM roles, Lambdas, Lambda permissions are all good.

```
# Lambda handler - This is the same for both GET and POST. I used the same in both lambdas integrated to GET and POST.

import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps("Hello World")
    }
```

```
################################################################################
# REST API and Resource
################################################################################
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "hello_world_v1" {
  name = "hello_world_v1"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "hello_world_v1" {
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.root_resource_id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.id
  path_part = "test"
}

################################################################################
# GET - method and integration
################################################################################
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "hello_world_v1_get" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.hello_world_v1.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"

}
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "hello_world_v1_get" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.hello_world_v1_get.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.hello_world_v1_get.http_method
  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri = aws_lambda_function.lambda_hello_world_v1_get.invoke_arn
# I initially didn't use this request template.
# I tried this after reading it somewhere while I was attempting to search for a solution. 
# However,using or not using, didn't work out.
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode(
      {
        statusCode = 200
      }
    )
  }
}

################################################################################
# POST - method and integration
################################################################################
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "hello_world_v1_post" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.hello_world_v1.id
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "hello_world_v1_post" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.hello_world_v1_post.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.hello_world_v1_post.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri = aws_lambda_function.lambda_hello_world_v1_post.invoke_arn
}

################################################################################
# Stage and Deployment
################################################################################
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "hello_world_v1" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_method.hello_world_v1_get,
    aws_api_gateway_method.hello_world_v1_post
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "hello_world_v1" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.hello_world_v1.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.id
  stage_name    = "development"
}
```

Comment: Why is the GET `type = "MOCK"` and has a `request_template`?

Comment: Hi, I edited it. It's "AWS_PROXY". I was trying what would happen if its "MOCK" and forgot to change it. The behavior is the same. As for the request template, I was reading on another StackOverflow post that for GET, it is needed (unsure why). However, this too did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_integration):

> integration_http_method - (Optional) The integration HTTP method (GET,
> POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONs, ANY, PATCH) specifying how API
> Gateway will interact with the back end. Required if type is AWS,
> AWS_PROXY, HTTP or HTTP_PROXY. Not all methods are compatible with all
> AWS integrations. e.g., Lambda function can only be invoked via POST.

In a very simple way, the `http_method` attribute refers to the HTTP Method of your endpoint, the `integration_http_method` is the HTTP method of the call that API Gateway will do to invoke the Lambda function.

Just change it to POST:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "hello_world_v1_get" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.hello_world_v1.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.hello_world_v1_get.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.hello_world_v1_get.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri = aws_lambda_function.lambda_hello_world_v1_get.invoke_arn
# I initially didn't use this request template.
# I tried this after reading it somewhere while I was attempting to search for a solution. 
# However,using or not using, didn't work out.
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode(
      {
        statusCode = 200
      }
    )
  }
}
```